# Excel Table numbering issue. Tables are not numbered sequentially when worksheets are copied within workbook

Tags: excel

Using Excel 2013 64 bit.

I'm copying worksheets with formatted Tables so that each new worksheet has a template for me to work on. I update the data from an external source and the Table format is adjusted to the new number of rows required. This works great and allows my data to be sorted and filtered. I have 4 formatted Tables on each sheet and 50 sheets in the workbook.

I have noticed that the file size is getting very large in this workbook, and then realised that Tables are not being numbered in a simple successive manner when they are copied. Instead, one, two or three digits are added to the table names. [Name manager showing ridiculous numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhTIV.png)

To check that this happens generally, I opened a new workbook and created 2 blank tables in each Sheet1 and Sheet2, and they are automatically named Table1 to Table4. Copying Sheet2 results in the copies of Table3 and Table4 to be Table36 and Table 47. If I copy this sheet, I get Table368 and Table 479.

If I highlight Table1 and Table2 and copy and paste to a new blank, uncopied sheet, I get Table 14 and Table25. This sort of renaming also occurs if I paste a Table in the same worksheet.

I have three questions:
Is this a bug? Is there a way to stop this happening?
Could this be contributing to my large filesize? A 50 worksheet workbook with 4 Tables on each sheet and between 100 and 3000 rows is 77MB.

Thanks!

Zsombor

Comment: how does the table numbers change if you copy only the sheet content?  (select cells > copy >paste. Not the whole sheet )

Comment: If I highlight Table1 and Table2 and copy and paste to a new blank, uncopied sheet, I get Table 14 and Table25. This sort of renaming also occurs if I paste a Table in the same worksheet.
Edited the original post.

Comment: IMHO : bug ? No.  contributing to large filesize? Maybe. It is a testable idea. Just crate the tables & sheet manually, and compare the size. stop this happening? Other that manually renaming the table, I don't see how. (Unless you are willing to reproduce the table via VBA)

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea until I saw 
VLOOKUP([@[field1]],Table1535660646872768185899397101105109113117121125129133137141177188[[field in other table]:[another field in second table]],2,0)
in a cell!

At a small scale, with two Tables on 4 sheets, one workbook the sheets copied, the other workbook they're created anew, the filesizes are identical. 

So this issue may not be causing my filesize problem, but I was surprised at the numbering process. I will try to copy tables with VBA and rename each Table relative to the worksheet e.g. Table220_1 through to Table220_4 etc.